# selecting only one record

Tags: php, pdo

Here in a.php file only 1 row is getting displayed.I used fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) stll i didnt get whole of the rows from chatlog.
where is the problem?

a.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
Include ('connect.php');
$query = $handler->prepare("SELECT message FROM chatlog");
$query->execute();
while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
    $message = $row['message'];
    $query = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM smilies"); 
    $query->execute();
    while ($row = $query->fetch()) { 
        $emoji = $row['emoji'];
        $smiley = "<img src='image/" . $row['smiley'] . "'/>";
        $message = str_replace($emoji, $smiley, $message); 
    }
    print_r("$message");
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `$query` variable. You are overwriting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
Include ('connect.php');

$smileys = $handler->query("SELECT emoji, smiley FROM smilies")->fetchAll(); 
$query   = $handler->query("SELECT message FROM chatlog");
foreach($query as $row)
{
    $message = $row['message'];
    foreach($smileys as $sm)
    { 
        $smiley  = "<img src='image/$sm[smiley]'/>";
        $message = str_replace($sm['emoji'], $smiley, $message); 
    }
    echo $message;
}
```

Comment: it worked  but my strings are not getting replaced @Your Common Sense